# what i should do to insert data from json into sqlite in Android

Tags: android, json, sqlite, insert

Im creat sqlit database in android to store data from json in database to view data if app is offline 
Im add code to creat database and colum but I do not know how insert data from json to my DB.
what i should do to insert data from json into sqlite
What i should add in code to do that ?

SQLiteOpenHelper

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class BookingTabel extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String DB_NAME = "myDB";

    // Books table name
   private static final String TABLE_BOOKINDS = "bookings";

   // Books Table Columns names
   private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
   private static final String KEY_BOOKING_NUM = "booking_num";
   private static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
   private static final String KEY_BOOKING_START= "booking_start";
   private static final String KEY_BOOKING_END = "booking_end";
   private static final String KEY_PROPERTY = "property_type";
   private static final String KEY_CUSTOMER_ID = "customer_id";
   private static final String KEY_DESCRIPTION = "description";
   private static final String KEY_ACCEPT_STATUS = "accept_status";
   private static final String KEY_BOOLING_ADDRESS = "booking_address";
   private static final String KEY_PO_BOX = "po_box";
   private static final String KEY_CREATED = "created";
   private static final String KEY_POSTCODE = "postcode";
   private static final String KEY_STATE = "state";
   private static final String KEY_STREET_ADDRESS = "street_address";
   private static final String KEY_STREET_NUMBER = "street_number";
   private static final String KEY_SUBURB = "suburb";
   private static final String KEY_UNIT_LOT_NUMBER = "unit_lot_number";
   private static final String KEY_STATUS = "status";
   private static final String KEY_CONVERT_STATUS = "convert_status";
   private static final String KEY_QOUTE = "qoute";
   private static final String KEY_SUB_TOTAL = "sub_total";
   private static final String KEY_TOTAL_DISCOUNT = "total_discount";
   private static final String KEY_BOOKING_DISTANCE = "booking_distance";
   private static final String KEY_GST = "gst";
   private static final String KEY_ORIGINAL_BOOKING_ID = "original_booking_id";

   public BookingTabel(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null,DB_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

private static final String[] COLUMNS = {KEY_ID,KEY_BOOKING_NUM,KEY_TITLE,KEY_BOOKING_START,KEY_BOOKING_END,KEY_PROPERTY,
       KEY_CUSTOMER_ID,KEY_DESCRIPTION,KEY_ACCEPT_STATUS,KEY_BOOLING_ADDRESS,KEY_PO_BOX,KEY_CREATED ,
       KEY_POSTCODE,KEY_STATE,KEY_STREET_ADDRESS,KEY_STREET_NUMBER,KEY_SUBURB,KEY_UNIT_LOT_NUMBER,KEY_STATUS,
       KEY_CONVERT_STATUS,KEY_QOUTE,KEY_SUB_TOTAL,KEY_TOTAL_DISCOUNT,KEY_BOOKING_DISTANCE,KEY_GST,
       KEY_ORIGINAL_BOOKING_ID,};

   @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub

           // SQL statement to create book table
     String CREATE_BOOKINDS_TABLE =
     "CREATE TABLE booking ( " + "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY"+ "booking_num VARCHAR(250)"+ "title VARCHAR(250)"+
     "booking_start DATETIME "+"booking_end DATETIME "+
     "property_type VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'House'"+
     "customer_id INTEGER+description TEXT"+"accept_status VARCHAR(250)"+"booking_address VARCHAR(250)" +
     "po_box VARCHAR(250)"+ "created INTEGER"+ "postcode INTEGER"+"state VARCHAR(250)"+
     "street_address VARCHAR(250)"+"street_number INTEGER"+"suburb VARCHAR(250)"+"unit_lot_number INTEGER"+
     "status VARCHAR(250)"+"convert_status VARCHAR(250)"+"qoute FLOAT"+"sub_total FLOAT"+"total_discount FLOAT"+
     "booking_distance FLOAT"+"gst FLOAT"+"original_booking_id INTEGER )";


     // create books table
     db.execSQL(CREATE_BOOKINDS_TABLE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int arg1, int arg2) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS bookings");

     // create fresh books table
     this.onCreate(db);
     }

    public void addBookings(Bookings booking){
        Log.d("addBooking", booking.toString());

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_BOOKING_NUM,booking.getbookingnum());
        values.put(KEY_TITLE,booking.gettitle());
        values.put(KEY_BOOKING_START ,booking.getbookingstart() );
        values.put(KEY_BOOKING_END ,booking.getbooking_end() );
        values.put(KEY_PROPERTY ,booking.getpropertytype() );
        values.put(KEY_CUSTOMER_ID ,booking.getcustomer_id() );
        values.put( KEY_DESCRIPTION,booking.getdescription() );
        values.put( KEY_ACCEPT_STATUS,booking.getaccept_status() );
        values.put( KEY_BOOLING_ADDRESS,booking.getbookingaddress() );
        values.put( KEY_PO_BOX,booking.getpo_box() );
        values.put( KEY_CREATED,booking.getcreated() );
        values.put( KEY_POSTCODE,booking.getpostcode() );
        values.put( KEY_STATE,booking.getstate() );
        values.put( KEY_STREET_ADDRESS,booking.getstreet_address() );
        values.put( KEY_STREET_NUMBER,booking.getstreet_number() );
        values.put( KEY_SUBURB,booking.getsuburb() );
        values.put( KEY_UNIT_LOT_NUMBER,booking.getunit_lot_number() );
        values.put( KEY_STATUS,booking.getstatus() );
        values.put( KEY_CONVERT_STATUS,booking.getconvert_status() );
        values.put( KEY_QOUTE,booking.getqoute() );
        values.put( KEY_SUB_TOTAL,booking.getsub_total() );
        values.put( KEY_TOTAL_DISCOUNT,booking.gettotal_discount() );
        values.put( KEY_BOOKING_DISTANCE,booking.getbooking_distance() );
        values.put( KEY_GST,booking.getgst() );
        values.put( KEY_ORIGINAL_BOOKING_ID,booking.getoriginal_booking_id() );

        db.insert(TABLE_BOOKINDS, null, values);
        db.close();
    }


}
```

Bookings

```
public class Bookings {

    private int id;
    private String booking_num;
    private String title;
    private String booking_start;
    private String booking_end;
    private String property_type;
    private int customer_id;
    private String description;
    private String accept_status;
    private String booking_address;
    private String po_box;
    private int created;
    private int postcode;
    private String state;
    private String street_address;
    private int street_number;
    private String suburb;
    private int unit_lot_number;    
    private String status;
    private String convert_status;
    private Float qoute;
    private Float sub_total;
    private Float total_discount;
    private Float booking_distance;
    private Float gst;
    private int original_booking_id;

    public Bookings(){}

    public Bookings(String booking_num ,String title ,String booking_start ,String booking_end ,
            String property_type ,int customer_id ,String description ,String accept_status ,String booking_address ,
            String po_box ,int created ,int postcode ,String state ,String street_address ,int street_number ,
            String suburb ,int unit_lot_number ,String status ,String convert_status ,Float qoute ,Float sub_total ,
            Float total_discount ,Float booking_distance ,Float gst ,int original_booking_id){
            this.booking_num = booking_num;
            this.title = title;
            this.booking_start = booking_start;
            this.booking_end =booking_end ;
            this.property_type =property_type;
            this.customer_id = customer_id;
            this.description = description;
            this.accept_status = accept_status;
            this.booking_address = booking_address;
            this.po_box = po_box;
            this.created = created;
            this.postcode = postcode;
            this.state = state;
            this.street_address = street_address;
            this.street_number = street_number;
            this.suburb = suburb;
            this.unit_lot_number = unit_lot_number;
            this.status = status;
            this.convert_status = convert_status;
            this.qoute = qoute;
            this.sub_total = sub_total;
            this.total_discount = total_discount;
            this.booking_distance = booking_distance;
            this.gst = gst;
            this.original_booking_id = original_booking_id;
    }


    // ---- setter
    public void setId(int id){
           this.id = id;
    }

    public void setbookingnum(String booking_num){
           this.booking_num = booking_num;
    }

    public void settitle(String title){
        this.title = title;
    }
    public void setbookingstart(String booking_start){
        this.booking_start = booking_start;
    }
    public void setbookingend(String booking_end ){
        this.booking_end  = booking_end ;
    }
    public void setpropertytype(String property_type){
        this.property_type  = property_type;
    }
    public void setcustomerid(int customer_id){
        this.customer_id = customer_id;
    }
    public void setdescription(String description){
        this.description = description;
    }
    public void setacceptstatus(String accept_status){
        this.accept_status = accept_status;
    }
    public void setbookingaddress(String booking_address){
        this.booking_address = booking_address;
    }
    public void setpobox(String po_box ){
        this.po_box = po_box ;
    }
    public void setcreated(int created){
        this.created = created ;
    }
    public void setpostcode(int postcode){
        this.postcode = postcode;
    }
    public void setstate(String state){
        this.state =state ;
    }
    public void setstreetaddress(String street_address){
        this.street_address = street_address ;
    }
    public void setstreetnumber(int street_number){
        this.street_number = street_number;
    }
    public void setsuburb(String suburb){
        this.suburb = suburb;
    }
    public void setunit_lot_number(int unit_lot_number ){
        this.unit_lot_number = unit_lot_number;
    }
    public void setstatus(String status){
        this.status =status ;
    }
    public void setconvert_status(String convert_status){
        this.convert_status =convert_status ;
    }
    public void setqoute(Float qoute){
        this.qoute = qoute;
    }
    public void setsubtotal(Float sub_total ){
        this.sub_total  =sub_total  ;
    }
    public void settotal_discount(Float total_discount){
        this.total_discount =total_discount ;
    }
    public void setbookingdistance(Float booking_distance){
        this.booking_distance =booking_distance ;
    }
    public void setgst(Float gst){
        this.gst = gst;
    }
    public void setoriginal_booking_id(int original_booking_id){
        this.original_booking_id = original_booking_id ;
    }


    // --- getter ---


    public int getId(){
           return id;
    }
    public String getbookingnum(){
           return booking_num;
    }
    public String gettitle(){
           return title ;
    }
    public String getbookingstart(){
           return booking_start ;
    }
    public String getbooking_end(){
           return  booking_end;
    }
    public String getpropertytype(){
           return  property_type;
    }
    public int getcustomer_id(){
           return customer_id ;
    }
    public String getdescription(){
           return  description;
    }
    public String getaccept_status(){
           return  accept_status;
    }
    public String getbookingaddress(){
           return booking_address ;
    }
    public String getpo_box(){
           return  po_box;
    }
    public int getcreated(){
           return  created;
    }
    public int getpostcode(){
           return postcode ;
    }
    public String getstate(){
           return state ;
    }
    public String getstreet_address(){
           return street_address ;
    }
    public int getstreet_number(){
           return street_number ;
    }
    public String getsuburb(){
           return suburb ;
    }
    public int getunit_lot_number(){
           return unit_lot_number ;
    }
    public String getstatus(){
           return  status;
    }
    public String getconvert_status(){
           return  convert_status;
    }
    public Float getqoute(){
           return qoute ;
    }
    public Float getsub_total(){
           return  sub_total;
    }
    public Float gettotal_discount(){
           return  total_discount;
    }
    public Float getbooking_distance(){
           return  booking_distance;
    }
    public Float getgst(){
           return  gst;
    }
    public int getoriginal_booking_id(){
           return original_booking_id ;
    }


    public String toString(){
        return "Booking  >> id:"+id+" | booking_num:"+booking_num+" | title:"+title+
                " | booking_start"+booking_start+" | booking_end"+booking_end+" | property_type"+property_type+
                " | customer_id "+customer_id +" |description "+description+" | accept_status"+accept_status+
                " | booking_address"+booking_address+" | po_box"+po_box+" | created"+created+" | postcode"+postcode+
                " | state"+state+" | street_address"+street_address+" | street_number"+street_number+
                " | suburb"+suburb+" | unit_lot_number"+unit_lot_number+" | status"+status+
                " | convert_status"+convert_status+" | qoute"+qoute+" | sub_total"+sub_total+
                " | total_discount"+total_discount+" | booking_distance"+booking_distance+" | gst"+gst+
                " | original_booking_id"+original_booking_id;
                        }


}
```

allbookingfrag

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

public class allbookingfrag extends Fragment {

    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyApp_Settings";
    private static final String givenUsername = "email";
    private static final String givenPassword = "password";

    private static final String TAG_RESULT = "result";
    private static final String TAG_BOOKING_NUM = "booking_num";
    private static final String TAG_TITLE = "title";
    private static final String TAG_STATUS = "status";
    private static final String TAG_BOOKING_START = "booking_start";
    private static final String TAG_BOOKING_END = "booking_end";
    private static final String TAG_QOUTE = "qoute";
    private static final String TAG_BOOKING_ADDRESS = "booking_address";
    private static final String TAG_CUSTOMER = "customer";
    private static final String TAG_CUSTOMER_NAME = "name";
    String result = null;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> resultList;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.allbookingfrag, container, false);

            SharedPreferences settings = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
            String email = settings.getString("email",givenUsername);
            String password = settings.getString("password",givenPassword);
            System.out.println("In allbooking activity names is : " + email + "password is : " + password );

            connectWithHttpGet(email, password );

            resultList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

           ListView listallbooking = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listallbooking); 

           return rootView;


    }


private void connectWithHttpGet(String email, String password ) {

        class HttpGetAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                // As you can see, doInBackground has taken an Array of Strings as the argument
                //We need to specifically get the givenUsername and givenPassword
                String email = params[0];
                String password = params[1];
            //  String uuid = params[2];
                System.out.println("paramUsername: " + email + " paramPassword is : " + password + "paramuuid is: ");

                // Create an intermediate to connect with the Internet
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                // Sending a GET request to the web page that we want
                // Because of we are sending a GET request, we have to pass the values through the URL
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("xxxxxxxxxx?email=" + email + "&password=" + password +"&uuid=fdgsfsdfsfsf"+"&mode=booking" );
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();


                                try {
                                    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);


                                    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                                    String jsonStr = null;
                                    jsonStr = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
                                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                                    // Getting JSON Array node
                                    JSONObject resultObj = jsonObj.getJSONObject("result");
                                    JSONArray resultArr = resultObj.getJSONArray("result");
                                    //Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);


                                    // looping through All Contacts
                                    for (int i = 0; i < resultArr.length(); i++) {
                                        JSONObject c = resultArr.getJSONObject(i);
                                        String booking_num = c.getString(TAG_BOOKING_NUM);
                                        String title = c.getString(TAG_TITLE);

                                /*      String splittitle= title;
                                        String [] mysplit_title = null;
                                        mysplit_title = splittitle.split("-");
                                        String First_title=mysplit_title[0];
                                        String Qoute_title=mysplit_title[1];
                                        String Username_title=mysplit_title[2];*/

                                        String status = c.getString(TAG_STATUS);
                                        String booking_start = c.getString(TAG_BOOKING_START);

                                        String my_starttime=booking_start;
                                                String [] my_date_time_start = null;
                                                my_date_time_start = my_starttime.split(" ");
                                                String Date_str_start=my_date_time_start[0];
                                                String Time_str_start=my_date_time_start[1];


                                        String booking_end = c.getString(TAG_BOOKING_END);

                                        String my_endtime=booking_start;
                                        String [] my_date_time_end = null;
                                        my_date_time_end = my_endtime.split(" ");
                                        String Date_str_end=my_date_time_end[0];
                                        String Time_str_end=my_date_time_end[1];

                                        String qoute = c.getString(TAG_QOUTE);
                                        String booking_address = c.getString(TAG_BOOKING_ADDRESS);
                                    //  System.out.println("booking_num: " + booking_num + " title is : " + title + "booking_start: "+ booking_start);

                                        JSONObject customer = c.getJSONObject(TAG_CUSTOMER);
                                        String name = customer.getString(TAG_CUSTOMER_NAME);

                                        BookingTabel db = new BookingTabel(getActivity());
                                        // tmp hashmap for single contact
                                        HashMap<String, String> result3 = new HashMap<String, String>();

                                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                                        result3.put(TAG_BOOKING_NUM, booking_num);
                                        result3.put(TAG_TITLE, title);
                                        result3.put(TAG_STATUS, status);
                                        result3.put(TAG_BOOKING_START, Time_str_start);
                                        result3.put(TAG_BOOKING_END, Time_str_end);
                                        result3.put(TAG_QOUTE, qoute);
                                        result3.put(TAG_BOOKING_ADDRESS, booking_address);
                                        result3.put(TAG_CUSTOMER_NAME, name);


                                        // Hashmap for ListView
                                    //    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> resultList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                                        // adding contact to contact list
                                        resultList.add(result3);
                                        System.out.println("resultList: " + resultList);

                                    }

                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                return null;


            }

            // Argument comes for this method according to the return type of the doInBackground() and
            //it is the third generic type of the AsyncTask
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

         ListView listallbooking = (ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listallbooking); 

           ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), resultList,
                        R.layout.list_item_allbooking,
                        new String[] { TAG_TITLE,TAG_STATUS, TAG_BOOKING_START,
                        TAG_BOOKING_END,TAG_QOUTE,TAG_BOOKING_ADDRESS,TAG_CUSTOMER_NAME }, new int[] {
                        R.id.listtitle,R.id.liststatus,
                        R.id.listbooking_start, R.id.listbooking_end,R.id.listqoute,R.id.listbooking_address,R.id.listcustomername});
                listallbooking.setAdapter(adapter);
            //  System.out.println("resultList: " + resultList);
            //    setOnItemClickListener
                listallbooking.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int postion,
                            long arg3) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Intent detailesitem = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(), estimates.class); 
                        startActivity(detailesitem);
                    }
                });


            }           
        }

        // Initialize the AsyncTask class
        HttpGetAsyncTask httpGetAsyncTask = new HttpGetAsyncTask();
        // Parameter we pass in the execute() method is relate to the first generic type of the AsyncTask
        // We are passing the connectWithHttpGet() method arguments to that
        httpGetAsyncTask.execute(email, password ); 

    }



}
```

Comment: Can you post a model of your json

Comment: You take so much of time to respond???

Comment: thank you , I need the code that do insert in sqlite from json , how i do it

Comment: POST YOUR JSON DATA HERE. So that i can give you an idea.

Comment: this is online viewer for json data [link](http://pastebin.com/KJPXMtah)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON seems to be very big. Here i have posted a model...

=> Get a json from server
=> Parse it to strings  while you insert into database

Declare the following immediately after extending activiy

```
private static final String TABLE_BERTH = "berth";
private static final String KEY_BID = "berth_id";
private static final String KEY_CLASS_NO = "class_no";
private static final String KEY_CLASS_NAME = "class_name";
private static final String KEY_SEAT_NO = "seat_no";
private static final String KEY_SEAT_POS = "seat_pos";

private JSONArray mComments = null;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mCommentList;
```

In a method to add into db

```
 DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext()); // In your case,handler  name is  Booking tabel

             mCommentList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    String  URL  = "your url here";

             String json =null;
            JSONObject jsonObj = null;
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("some_param", "some_value"));

        ServiceHandler jsonParser = new ServiceHandler();
      json = jsonParser.makeServiceCall(URL, ServiceHandler.POST, params);         
                 try {
                jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
                if (jsonObj != null) {

                    mComments = jsonObj.getJSONArray("berths");
                     SQLiteDatabase database = db.getWritableDatabase();    

                     database.beginTransaction();
                    try{
                        for (int i = 0; i < mComments.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = mComments.getJSONObject(i);

                            // gets the content of each tag


                            int class_no = c.getInt(TAG_CLASS_NO);
                            String class_name = c.getString(TAG_CLASS_NAME);
                            int seat_no = c.getInt(TAG_SEAT_NO);
                            String seat_pos = c.getString(TAG_SEAT_POS);

                            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                            values.put(KEY_CLASS_NO, class_no);
                            values.put(KEY_CLASS_NAME, class_name);  
                            values.put(KEY_SEAT_NO, seat_no);  
                            values.put(KEY_SEAT_POS, seat_pos);  


                            database.insert(TABLE_BERTH,null,values);

                    }
                    // Transaction is successful and all the records have been inserted
                    database.setTransactionSuccessful();
                    }catch(Exception e){

                    }finally{
                    //End the transaction
                        database.endTransaction();
                    }   




                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: thanks you,,, But after insert data done and Re-run app the data store in new rows , not update in the old rows , so what should i do to update in rows not add new data for each run app.

Answer (score 2):

for better maintainable code I would recommend to used Android Volley library. You get async API to call rest API with callbacks giving your JSON objects directly.

And use GSON library to convert JSON to Java object like the one you defined(Bookings). Only thing you need to do is to define the Bookings member variable names same as the keys in JSON structure.

now you should have a utility method to insert in to db by reading values from your Bookings object.

It then makes a maintainable error free code.